# Python module "logging" double output

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I want to use the `logging` module, but I'm having some trouble because it is outputting twice. I've read a lot of posts with people having the same issue and `log.propagate = False` or `log.handlers.pop()´ fixed it for them. This doesn't work for me.

I have a file called **logger.py** that looks like this:

```
import logging

def __init__():
    log = logging.getLogger("output")
    filelog = logging.FileHandler("output.log")
    formatlog = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s")
    filelog.setFormatter(formatlog)
    log.addHandler(filelog)
    log.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    return log
```

So that I from multiple files can write:

```
import logger
log = logger.__init__()
```

But this is giving me issues. So I've seen several solutions, but I don't know how to incorporate it in multiple scripts without defining the logger in all of them.

Comment: "it is outputting twice": to where and where? To `output.log` and stderr? In any case yes it looks like you should be setting `log.propagate = False` in your function. Or (less likely) does each message appear twice in `output.log`?

Comment: It outputs the same message twice to output.log, but I've written an answer to it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52141311/9875740

Comment: PS `log.propagate = False` would guard against every message also being written by the root logger, *if* the root has a handler. If this is the only configuration you do, that'll never happen so you actually don't have to touch `propagate`. But if you call logging.log(...), logging.debug(), ... or logging.critical(), they will "helpfully" create a root handler if there aren't any.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution which was really simple. All I needed to do was to add an `if` statement checking if the handlers already existed. So my `logger.py` file now looks like this:

```
import logging

def __init__():
    log = logging.getLogger("output")

    if not log.handlers:
        filelog = logging.FileHandler("output.log")
        formatlog = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s")
        filelog.setFormatter(formatlog)
        log.addHandler(filelog)
        log.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    return log
```

Answer (score 0):

multiple scripts lead to multiple processes. so you unluckily create multiple objects returned from the `logger.__init__()` function.

usually, you have one script which creates the logger and the different processes, 
but as i understand, you like to have multiple scripts logging to the same destination.

if you like to have multiple processes to log to the same destination, i recommend using inter process communication as "named pipes" or otherwise using a UDP/TCP port for logging.

There are also queue modules available in python to send a (atomic) logging entry to be logged in one part (compared to append to a file by multiple processes - which may lead from 111111\n and 22222\n to 11212121221\n\n in the file)

otherwise think about named pipes...

Code snippet for logging server
Note: i just assumed to log everything as  error...

```
import socket
import logging

class mylogger():
    def __init__(self, port=5005):
    log = logging.getLogger("output")
    filelog = logging.FileHandler("output.log")
    formatlog = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s")
    filelog.setFormatter(formatlog)
    log.addHandler(filelog)
    log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    self.log = log
    UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"  # localhost
    self.port = port
    self.UDPClientSocket = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    self.UDPClientSocket.bind((UDP_IP, self.port))
def pollReceive(self):
    data, addr = self.UDPClientSocket.recvfrom(1024)  # buffer size is 1024 bytes
    print("received message:", data)
    self.log.error( data )
pass

log = mylogger()

while True:
    log.pollReceive()
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think OP means multiple scripts running concurrently, just that he'd like to use this as a library routine in various scripts.

Comment: In certain cases yes.

Comment: Ah, then each time it's called it adds another handler to the logger :) In general you want to configure logging once, only. Shameless self-promo: https://github.com/Twangist/prelogging, a sensible API for setting up logging.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be very carefully by adding **new handler** to your logger with:

```
log.addHandler(...)
```

If you add more than one handler to your logger, you will get more than one outputs. Be aware that **this is only truth for logger which are running in the same thread**. If you are running a class which is derived from **Thread**, then it is the same thread. But if you are running a class which is derived from **Process**, then it is another thread. To ensure that you only have one handler for your logger according to this thread, you should use the following code (this is an example for SocketHandler):

```
logger_root = logging.getLogger()
if not logger_root.hasHandlers():
    socket_handler = logging.handlers.SocketHandler('localhost', logging.handlers.DEFAULT_TCP_LOGGING_PORT)
    logger_root.addHandler(socket_handler)
```